# Diagram similar to the UML Sequence Diagram with Archimate

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram, archimate

I tried to model a diagram similar to the UML Sequence Diagram with Archimate.
https://forum.archimatetool.com/index.php?topic=288.0 and http://www.hosiaisluoma.fi/ArchiMate-Cookbook.pdf chap. 2.9.6 say that this is possible by using data flow relationships between application components.

So I tried to create 2 application components and 2 request-response dataflows between them:

- component A and component B
- request 1 from A to B
- repsonse 1 from B to A
- request 2 from A to B
- response 2 from B to A

This was neither possible with ADOIT nor with Archi. Sparx EA allowed to create it. I could not find if the specification allows it, but in my experiance Archi is very much alligned with the spec, while EA is not.

So my questions are:

1. Which tool / diagram is correct according to the spec?
2. Is there another possibility to create a diagram similar to the UML Sequence Diagram with Archimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Metamodel

The metamodel of Archimate is less formally defined as for example UML, but we can find some information.

The first thing to look at is the [metamodel for the Application Layer](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/chap09.html#_Toc10045390)
[image]
Here we see **triggers / flows to** relations from/to the elements

- Application Service
- Application Event
- Applicaiton Internal Behavior Element

An **Application Component** however is an Application Internal Active Structure Element as we learn from a more detailed view on the same page

[image]

So this metamodel **does not allow** flow relations between Application Components

### Relationship Matrix

But these are not **all** the allowed relationships in ArchiMate. On [this page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/archimate3-doc/apdxb.html#_Toc10045493) there is an additional matrix with all the allowed relationships.

[image]

If you look closely you see that there is an **f** in the cell that represents represent Application Component x Application Component. **f** stand for **flow**

### Conclusion

**YES** flow relations between Application Components are allowed.

### BUT..

You can't *simulate* sequence diagrams using ArchiMate flows. A critical factor in sequence diagrams is, well the **sequence**. There is no way in Archimate to specify that one flow is supposed to be happen before another flow.

Comment: Many thanks. I did not know the matrix. It is very helpful. Yes, I am aware of the problem that I cannot really model a sequence with ArchiMate. But if you are committed to a tool then you have to take what’s there.

You say “YES flow relation*s* between Application Components are allowed”. So that does not disallow >1 dataflows in 1 direction, right?

Comment: Indeed, ArchiMate doesn't say anything about multiple relations of the same type between the same elements.